# digitalCrownRotation not updating value on text

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, watchos

I am building a simple water tracking app, and I want to use the digital crown for increasing/decreasing the value of drunk water.

However .digitalCrownRotation won't update the value. I have tried everything but without any luck.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var counter: Double = 0.0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("\(counter, specifier: "%.1f") L")
                    .focusable().digitalCrownRotation(self.$counter, from: 0, through: 5, by: 0.1, sensitivity: .medium, isContinuous: true, isHapticFeedbackEnabled: true)
            }
            Spacer()
            Button("Confirm", action: {
                print("ciao confirm")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works.  I built it in the simulator and used two fingers on my MacBook trackpad to move the crown.

Comment: For me it is not working. I use the two fingers to move the crown but the value remains 0.0

Comment: Make sure your mouse pointer is over the watch face.  I tested with Xcode 13.4.1.  Do you have the scrolling gesture enabled on your trackpad?

Comment: If I move my mouse pointer over the watch face, the crown won't move. However if I move the pointer over the crown, i can see it scrolling but does nothing. Yes the scrolling gesture is enabled ofc.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?  Have you changed any settings from a default new project?  Is this for a standalone watch app?

Comment: XCode is v13.4.1, haven't changed any settings. The project is started from an iOS app and later added the watch app. Maybe I should try making only the watchOS app?

Comment: Try a standalone watch app with your code above.  Check the version of the watchOS (Crown->Settings->General-About).  Mine is 8.5.